# Why isn't the BitmapData transparent?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
    var subimage = new Bitmap();
    subimage.bitmapData = new BitmapData(25, 25, true, 0);
    addChild(subimage);
```

From everything I've read, this should be transparent. I'm seeing a big black square. What could cause that?

Comment: this code is correct (except that you haven't typed your subimage variable) and works fine for me.

Comment: How do you embed the SWF? Do you use wmode=transparent?

Comment: I haven't been embedding the SWF - I just open it up using the standalone player. It seems like I've been leading you guys on a goose chase though, and the bug must be somewhere else. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense: I tried the following code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

public class TestBitMap extends Sprite
    {
        public function TestBitMap() {
            var imageYellow:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new BitmapData(100, 100, true, 0xFFFFFF00));
            var imageTransparent:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new BitmapData(100, 100, true, 0));
            var imageSemiTransparent:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new BitmapData(100, 100, true, 0x99000000));
            imageTransparent.x = 25;
            imageTransparent.y = 25;
            imageSemiTransparent.x = 50;
            imageSemiTransparent.y = 50;
            addChild(imageYellow);
            addChild(imageTransparent);
            addChild(imageSemiTransparent);
        }       
    }
}
```

And I got a yellow box with a semitransparent black box over it. The "imageTransparent" was completely invisible.

I also tried your method with creating the BitMap first, then changing the bitmapData. No difference, still invisible.

San.chez: 0 is equal to 0x00000000, no matter what. It is an unsigned integer, ActionScript doesn't magically change it. Your link is good though.

Comment: I seem to remember the MXML components doing something like this to the color argument (which gets converted from a string to a Color object), might have been there you've picked it up? :)

Comment: Hey Dennis. Thanks for the response. I'm accepting your answer because it was the closest to being right - I had forgotten to take some *other* code I wrote into account. This should really teach me to sleep on any bugs I find. To everyone: thanks for looking into this, even though it turned out to be nothing. Sorry.

Answer (score 13):

use this

```
new BitmapData(25, 25, true, 0x00000000);
```

instead of

```
new BitmapData(25, 25, true, 0);
```

0xFF000000 is black(0x000000) with alpha equal to 1

0x00000000 is black(0x000000) with alpha equal to 0

Here is a nice explanation how colors & alpha work: http://myflex.wordpress.com/2007/09/07/about-hex-color-codes-in-flex-as3/

//EDIT:

Dennis Krøger and strille are right, 0x00000000 == 0.
Looks like the problem is somewhere else, not in the code you pasted in.

Comment: there's no difference between 0 and 0x00000000 (or 0x0) since they all evaluate to zero (`trace(0x00000000 === 0); // prints true`), so there's something else causing the black square. But from a _readability_ point of view I think it's better to express it as a hexadecimal value since it's more obvious it represents a color value.

Answer (score 3):

ActionScript uses a 32-bit hexadecimal numbers to represent color values with transparency. ARGB colors as 32 bit variables are specified by 4 groups of 8 bits each / or 2 hex each:

In binary: AAAAAAAA RRRRRRRR GGGGGGGG BBBBBBBB

In hex: AA RR GG BB

A represents the alpha value (transparency), R is rd, G is green, B is blue. Each group defines intensity of each of the colors channels, A is alpha, R is red, G is green, B is blue. Full intensity on the alpha channel means no alpha (FF) and no intensity (00) means full alpha. So a transparent pixel color value is 0x00rrggbb.

Answer (score 3):

You can either create or pass [BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) to the constructor of a new [Bitmap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html) object, or edit it by reference after it is created.  Both options work:

```
package 
{
    //Imports
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    //Document Class
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        //Constructor
        public function Main() 
        {
            var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(200, 200, true, 0x5500FF00);
            var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmpData);

            addChild(bmp);

            var bmp2:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
            bmp2.bitmapData = new BitmapData(200, 200, true, 0x55FF0000);
            bmp2.x = bmp2.y = 200;

            addChild(bmp2);
        }
    }
}
```